# Executar uma função PHP como attributo html?

Tags: php, html, vue.js

O que preciso é o seguinte, tenho este código html:

```
<div php-if="{{valor}}>0">CONTEUDO QUE SERÁ MOSTRADO DINAMICAMENTE</div>
```

A variável "{{valor}}" já tenho como retornar dinamicamente. O que gostaria agora é de executar uma função em php que identificasse que estou fazendo uma comparação IF e caso me retornasse falso, essa tag inteira seria removida da string. O resultado seria uma string html, mas sem essa tag do exemplo.

OBS: É um pouco parecido com o que o Vue.js faz, mas quero fazer do lado do servidor via php.

Comment: Você quer comparar um valor que vem do vue pelo php?

Comment: Oi boa noite e obrigado pelo retorno. Não estou usando Vue.js, coloquei como exemplo apenas para melhor entendimento.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Solução do problema.]

Depois de muitas tentativas, segue o código que resolveu meu problema. Com ele eu posso ocultar ou exibir um elemento html usando um "IF" do php como attr do html. Lembrando que essa variável "{{value}}" vem do meu template via controller, logo o valor dela é dinamico.

Comment: ` $dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));` 
Modifiquei esta linha para corrigir problemas com a codificação do resultado

Comment: Walison, não poste código em forma de imagem. O site tem suporte para código fonte, basta você copiá-lo no editor, selecionado e pressionar o ataljo `Ctrl+K`, ou utilizar o botão `{}` do mesmo.

Comment: O tua variável `isValid` não serve para nada, estás a usa-la no `if` mas nunca vai entrar nesse `if` porque `isValid` vai ser sempre true no código que está na imagem

Comment: Sobre a variável isValid, discordo. Como disse isValid vai ser o resultado de {{valor}}>0 e essa variavel {{valor}} é alimentada dinamicamente, logo o bloco if se {{valor}} = 0, torna meu teste falso e caso seja 1, por exemplo, torna o código verdadeiro. Testei e resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Miguel, veja também que isValid está dentro de um eval.